# jQuery .load() with fadeIn effect

Tags: jquery, load, fadein

I'm trying to load #content of a url via AJAX using jQuery within #primary. It loads but doesn't fadeIn. What am I doing wrong?

```
$('.menu a').live('click', function(event) {
        var link = $(this).attr('href');
        $('#content').fadeOut('slow', function(){
            $('#primary').load(link+' #content', function(){
                $('#content').fadeIn('slow');
            });
        });
        return false;
    });
```

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Actually I was able to do it by applying the effect to the wrapper div instead...

```
$('#primary').fadeOut('slow', function(){
    $('#primary').load(link+' #content', function(){
        $('#primary').fadeIn('slow');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 10):

Just this:

```
$('.element').load('file.html',function(){}).hide().fadeIn();
```

Or to add this behaviour as default in the load() function:

```
$.fn.load_=$.fn.load;
$.fn.load=function(){
    return $.fn.load_.apply(this,arguments).hide().fadeIn();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

When using `load()` jQuery internally uses `html()` to updated your element. This means you can't apply any animation to it, as you're just updating the `innerHTML` property of the element.

Instead you'll need to write your own AJAX request to get the new HTML, put it in the element, then call `fadeIn()`.

```
$('.menu a').live('click', function(event) {
    var link = $(this).attr('href');

    $('#content').fadeOut('slow', function() {
        $.get(
            link +' #content', 
            function(data) {
                $("#primary").html(data).fadeIn('slow');
            }, 
            "html"
        );
    });
    return false;
});
```

I used `get()` here, but you could just as easily use `post()` or `ajax()`.

Also, just to note, `live()` has been deprecated. You should instead use `delegate()` or, if you are using jQuery 1.7+, `on()`.

Comment: It becomings really slow. It seems to be reloading every js scripts of the destination page. I also use the jQuery address plugin and it seems to break it somehow.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use .load() in fading effect like this

`$("#container").fadeOut("slow").load('data.html').fadeIn('slow');`

Answer (score 2):

I've found doing something like this works well...

$('#Div').fadeOut(0).fadeIn().load('foo.blah.html');

Answer (score 0):

This is the best way to fade in/out it naturaly, first you hide your container then you load your page in this container (it will be loaded but hidden) then just use the Jquery function .fadeIn() and it will unhide it adding the special effect.

```
$(".myClass").click(function () 
{
    $("#Container").hide();
    $("#Container").load("magasin.html");
    $("#Container").fadeIn(); 
});
```