# Fadein With JQUERY on click with external html file

Tags: jquery, html, css

So I have a page, and when a user clicks on one of the navigation links instead of changing page, it just loads the content from those pages into the div on the main page. I did this through using JQuery the .load  and both of the tests that I tried, work perfectly with the .load.

What I wanted to see now was if instead just loading the content in  all at once I wanted to fade in slowly to make more effect, and I was curious as whether I could do this the same way as I did the .load.

This is the code that I used in JQUERY to do the .load on the click:

```
   function loadPage(){

   $('#page').load ('art1.html #content');

    }
```

and then this function is called in the HTML as Follows:

```
   <a href="#" onclick="loadPage();">click me</a>
```

This works perfectly fine but I would prefer it if it faded in instead:

I know that I cannot just change the .load to to the .FadeIn as of the way that this written but how would I write the .fadeIn function.

page= The Div on the main page that I want the content loaded into

content= The div on the external HTML file where the content is written

Comment: You should always search the Stack Overflow and Google before asking a question on here :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try hiding the div before loading data into it, then fade it in after the data is loaded:

```
function loadPage() {
    var $page = $('#page');
    //if you have other content already in #page
    //and would like it to fade out, use fadeOut()
    //instead of hide()
    $page.hide(function () {
        $page.load('art1.html #content', function () {
            $page.fadeIn();
        });
    })
}
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/CkuRh/) (ignore what's being loaded, it was the simplest thing to do within this example :)

Comment: Sorry, Only just saw yours, Thank you, Yes that one worked :), Thank you Very much :)

Answer (score 0):

Actually I was able to do it by applying the effect to the wrapper div instead...

```
$('#PageWrapper').fadeIn('slow', function(){
   $('#page').load ('art1.html #content');
});
```

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9337220/jquery-load-with-fadein-effect)

Comment: I tried this but it just made everything fade out instead, nothing faded back in.

Comment: i've simplified it. Put you div inside another div called `id="PageWrapper"`

Answer (score 0):

This code will fade in over a period of 1/2 sec.

```
function loadPage(){
$('#page').hide().load('art1.html #content', function() {
     $('#page').fadeIn(500);
};
```

}