# How to add a fade effect to a .load-Function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

i got this code for requesting content from .php Files from my server:

```
function contentloader(dataid) {
            $("#content").load("controller.php?id="+dataid+"", {}, function() { $(this).fadeIn(900); });
        }
```

Links in my template working with "javascript:contentloader('sitename');" for example:

```
<a href=javascript:contentloader('home');>Home</a>
```

The content loads, but the fade-effect doesn't work, and i have no clue why. Maybe you can help me. Thank you very much.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9337220/jquery-load-with-fadein-effect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For fadeIn() to work the element has to be hidden first.

So try to use fadeTo() - fadeOut the existing content then fadeIn the new content

```
function contentloader(dataid) {
    $("#content").fadeTo(200, .5, function () {
        $(this).load("controller.php?id=" + dataid + "", {}, function () {
            $(this).fadeTo('normal', 1);
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: That works not as fine as i wanted. If i click on a link the content comes in, fades out, and fades in again. How to fade out before it loads? It doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: @user3279720 use the fadeOut callback to load the content

Comment: Working now. Can i manipulate the DOM, so my "current" link gets the class "current"? And can i also manipulate the URL so if someone is refreshing the site, he's coming back where he was, and not to the index?

//Edit: Ok the second question is partial solved. I found the links, but how can i manipulate the URL for the user? the url would be index.php?id=sitename