# fade from one image to another on div reload

Tags: jquery, html

I am running a python bottle web server for a python script that is generating new data and I am using the web interface for the front end. I have several divs on my front end page that I have set to refresh periodically. Eg.:

```
<script>
function autoRefresh_z()
{
     $("#z_div").load("z_div.tpl.html");
 }
 setInterval('autoRefresh_z()', 1000);
            </script>
<script>$(document).ready(function() {$("#z_div").load("z_div.tpl.html")})</script>
```

makes the `<div class="col-md-8" id="z_div"></div>` refresh every second.

This works well for changes in text (and I update a progress bar this way) but where I want to include a changing image, it flickers on the reload as the new image is loaded. Is there a straightforward way with javascript to reload this div but fade from one image to the next?

**EDIT:** Conventional `fade` seems to go from image --> white --> image (at least how I have it). I would like to go image --> image. Is this possible?

Comment: there is, you need to include `fade` in order to change one image to another

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery .load() with fadeIn effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9337220/jquery-load-with-fadein-effect)